# Is there an equivalent of OFFSET for array contents

Tags: excel-formula

I would like to dynamically modify the dimensions of array contents just like OFFSET's height and width do with ranges.

Let A1:A5 equal to 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
if I want to get the first 3 values with offset (using a range):
=OFFSET(A1:A5,,3,1) => {1;2;3}

But this doesn't work:
=OFFSET({1;2;3;4;5},,,3,1)

Is there an equivalent to OFFSET but for array contents? This is of course part of a much bigger array formula which forces me to work with array contents instead of ranges.

Of course I could easily do it with VBA but I'd rather not, let's call this company limitations...

Thank you very much for your help.

PS: first time posting here, any remarks/advice to improve my questions are most welcome.

Comment: **OFFSET** requires a valid cell or actual range of cells as a starting point as far as know otherwise it won't work. **INDEX** would be the closest option but it will be much more complicated when you try to replicate height and width as in OFFSET. A work around would be using helper columns/rows/ranges/sheets to put the range(s) down in actual cells, and use OFFSET as you used to.

Answer (score 0):

Hi & Welcome to the forum. I think you are almost correct - the only thing you need to do is to press Ctrl+Shift+Enter in order to turn your OFFSET formula into an Array formula:

[image]

In the example below I have combined your OFFSET with SUMPRODUCT formula (which works with ranges and arrays). As you can see the result of SUMPRODUCT function is correct (i.e. sum of first 3 values):

[image]

Let me know if this is what you were looking for.

Comment: The op did not want to use a range but an entered array like `{1;2;3;4;5}` directly in the formula.

Answer (score 0):

You can use INDEX to return an array:

```
INDEX({1;2;3;4;5},N(IF({1},ROW(INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,1):INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,3)))))
```

This will force any formula that uses this to become an array formula and as such must be entered with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

Change the `,1` to the start position desired and the `3` to the end position desired.

```
N(IF({1},ROW(INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,1):INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,3))))
```

Creates an array of numbers from the `1` to the `3` in this case.  Which is passed to the INDEX and the INDEX will then return an array of the array `{1,2,3}`

As you can see with this sum of that array:

[image]

Comment: Wow that's an awesome formula ! I love it thank you!
I'm not super sure how N() and IF({1}) are essential, but the formula does not work without it so fair enough...
How would I adapt that formula to get several sets of Array contents?
Specifically to cut the Array content less, dynamically.
So first iteration in your first example could be 
={1;2}
Then second iteration:
={1;2;3}

And so on. 
This would ultimately result in SUM() giving out an array in your last example:
={3,6,10,15} 

Do you see what I mean?

Comment: You can't do that sort of thing with formula. You can loop once not multiple. It would require vba